# muuri-react with Redux causes "Invariant failed: The item has not been setted yet"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, muuri

I am passing a list of objects to `muuri-react` to display in a draggable grid layout and it works fine when I pass an explicitly defined list of objects, but when I use a redux selector to get the data it breaks even though it's the same data.

Here is an example that reproduces this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-montalcini-rbdso?file=/src/components/pages/Notes.js

I render two Muuri grids one with with `notes1` and one with `notes2` which are identical objects, but somehow `notes1` works fine and `notes2` doesn't render properly (not draggable) and causes the error `Invariant failed: The item has not been setted yet` if you try navigating to another tab like Reminders. I check that `notes1` and `notes2` are equal with lodash console log.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { MuuriComponent } from "muuri-react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchNotes } from "../../state/slices/notesSlice";
import _ from "lodash";

const Notes = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Fetch notes
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchNotes());
  }, []);

  let notes1 = [
    {
      id: "1",
      title: "Title 1",
      text:
        "Text 1 - Est libero a lorem curabitur auctor at viverra ipsum id euismod condimentum dolor vel sit nullam libero nec"
    },
    { id: "2", title: "Title 2", text: "Text 2 - Auctor dolor vitae nullam" },
    {
      id: "3",
      title: "Title 3",
      text:
        "Text 3 - Viverra nunc enim adipiscing lorem laoreet id nec condimentum est odio dolor sagittis in libero nullam ipsum"
    }
  ];
  let notes2 = useSelector((state) => Object.values(state.notes.byId));

  console.log("_.isEqual(notes1, notes2)?", _.isEqual(notes1, notes2));

  return (
    <StyledNotes>
      <MuuriWrapper>
        <MuuriComponent dragEnabled dragFixed>
          {notes1.map((note, i) => (
            <StyledNote key={i}>
              <h3>{note.title}</h3>
              <div>{note.text}</div>
            </StyledNote>
          ))}
        </MuuriComponent>
      </MuuriWrapper>
      <MuuriWrapper>
        <MuuriComponent dragEnabled dragFixed>
          {notes2.map((note, i) => (
            <StyledNote key={i}>
              <h3>{note.title}</h3>
              <div>{note.text}</div>
            </StyledNote>
          ))}
        </MuuriComponent>
      </MuuriWrapper>
    </StyledNotes>
  );
};

const MuuriWrapper = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid black;
`;

const StyledNotes = styled.div`
  padding: 30px;
`;

const StyledNote = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.border};
  border-radius: ${({ theme }) => theme.borderRadius};
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.background};
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 250px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;

  &.muuri-item-dragging {
    z-index: 1;
  }
`;

export default Notes;
```

Comment: Hi, can you update your question here to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the specific and relevant code you've an issue with?

Comment: @DrewReese My question includes a link to the `Notes.js` file that produces this bug in my codesandbox project. I'm unable to make a single-file reproducible example because I was unable to figure out the root cause. The problem goes away if I define the items directly even though they're identical, so I can't reproduce the bug without the Redux store.

Comment: External resources tend to decay.... code included with the question persists for all future readers. It's part of what make a question possibly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log `notes2`, you will see that it changes from the length of 0 (start request), to the length of 3 (fully requested)

I see that the issue is due to the dynamic aspect of `notes2`, while it seems that the murri lib will load well for the static one (`notes1`)

So a quick fix could be to make sure to load MurriGrid after `notes2` is fully requested, so it will avoid first time load for the init one (length of 0) then rerender to fully-loaded one (length of 3) - which caused unexpected behavior

```
      {notes2.length && (
        <MuuriWrapper>
          <MuuriGrid>
            {notes2.map((note, i) => (
              <StyledNote key={i}>
                <h3>{note.title}</h3>
                <div>{note.text}</div>
              </StyledNote>
            ))}
          </MuuriGrid>
        </MuuriWrapper>
      )}
```

[image: Edit reverent-faraday-nlwlt]